# Android How to make a call that includes "#" or "p" in the dial?

Tags: android

I need to make calls in my Android app that includes "#" or "p" in the dial.

If I use the next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:629941945#22412"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

It makes the call to the number **629941945 without the # and 22412**.

And if I use the next code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:629941945p22412"));
    startActivity(intent);
```

It makes the call without the **"p": 62994194522412.**

There is a form that I can solve it?

Comment: Will u please let us know , what could be the use case of this. Which country support characters/Special char in Phone Number.??

Comment: I'm doing an app witch calls to a VO IP number. This number has to call to the phone number that I pass after the pauses.

Answer (score 9):

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode("*111*2#")));
startActivity(shortcutIntent);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `tel:629941945%2322412` instead of `tel:629941945#22412`

`%23` will be replaced with `#`

Answer (score 3):

Try to use others symbol for pause. Look at http://androidforums.com/android-applications/6733-how-do-i-dial-extension.html or http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7514
But! As I see threre are not one solution and this is depends of phone model

Answer (score 1):

> Some phones don’t have “p” character, but “,” (comma), somewhere it is
> “T” and if your phone does not have these fancy characters available,
> try “*” or “#“. Hopefully one of this characters will work. Beware, on
> some phones are letters case sensitive, so P can not work.
>
> - http://rekrowten.wordpress.com/2011/08/29/special-characters-in-telephone-number/

Answer (score 1):

Pause is not supported in the tel URI spec.

http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt

As stated in another answer `%23` can be used to substitute for `#`.

Answer (score 1):

I used Intent.ACTION_DIAL instead of Intent.ACTION_CALL

```
val intent = Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
    Uri.parse("tel:$phoneNumber")
)
startActivity(intent)
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can not parse such special numbers with an URI since these are not compliant to tel: standard. (http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3966.txt Page 6ff)
You might want to use [ACTION_DIAL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_DIAL) and give the user the possibility to enter the number himself. Maybe then the phone interprets this as the pause signal p is intended for. To send such pause signals, check Alex Klimashevsky's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "," (comma) instead of p. No idea about "#" though, sorry.