# How to use Uri.parse() with # at the end

Tags: android, parsing, uri, gsm

I try to use GSM codes to transfer my calls with an android app.
For example, if I call :  **21*otherNumber# 
All my calls will be transfered on otherNumber.

My code:

```
Uri transfert = Uri.parse( "tel:**21*" + numero + "#");
Intent intent = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_CALL, transfert );
startActivity(intent);
```

However, Uri.parse() has for definition:
" A URI reference includes a URI and a fragment, the component of the URI following a '#'  "

So, it removes the # but I need it. The GSM code can't works without it.

Somebody would have an idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can't dial phone number with extensions, it's a known issue ([see this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7514)).

According to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774884/android-how-to-make-a-call-that-includes-or-p-in-the-dial), you may try to add `%23` like `Uri.parse( "tel:**21*" + numero + "%23");`

Comment: I missed this post, thank you it works !
I will also give a look at ACTION_CALL.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a URI encoded hash to parse it through the URI.

```
public static final String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
```

It will keep the URI encoded hash and send the USSD message over GSM as you have specified.