# Failure to pass # as input in dialer application

Tags: android, android-studio, development-environment

I am building an android dialer application, but when my input contains string of form *123# the number which gets dialed is *123.
How can I pass # also in the dialer application?
Below is the code:

```
 public void onDial(View v) {
    if (input.getText().length() <3) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please Enter the Valid Number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String hash = input.getText().toString();
        if (hash.contains("#")) {
            hash.replace("#", "%23");
        }
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + hash));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }else{
            requestCallPermission();
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You where close! Encoding will work, but the replace method returns a new string! :-)

```
   if (hash.contains("#")) {
        hash = hash.replace("#", "%23"); // Need to set the hash reference to the new string generated by replace()!
    }
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + hash));
```

Refs:

http://zetcode.com/kotlin/strings/

[How to use Uri.parse() with # at the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570488/how-to-use-uri-parse-with-at-the-end)

Comment: @Samin If you found this helpful pls remember to mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Two years later ... he never did :-)