# android starting a phone call intent with # in the URI

Tags: android, android-intent, phone-call

I tried do the below for a phone call intent and I still keep getting the **"#"** removed from the number been called. Please see code below... The # at the end get translated into a %23 on printing out the contents of the string to a console. I am testing on a Samsung S4 phone which then generates a USSD code error running. Is there something wrong with the phone or the code below

```
Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);    
phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + Uri.encode("*222*"+ rechargeNumber + "#");));        
startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use `Uri.encode()`.

Use the following code. I think it will help you.

```
String uri = "tel:" +"*222*"+ rechargeNumber + "#" ;
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
 intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This was my initial code before I changed it to the one above after reading this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774884/android-how-to-make-a-call-that-includes-or-p-in-the-dial

Answer (score 0):

Intent you're looking for is android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED. 
This might be helpful to you 
[using android dialer in 3rd party app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3499550/using-android-dialer-in-3rd-party-app)