# How to parse '#' simbol using Uri.Parse in android

Tags: android, android-intent, uri

Hy... I'm making a code like this :

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:*123#"));
startActivity(callIntent);
```

Above callIntent is used to call a phone number *123#, but when I run the code, It's just calling *123 without #. I have tried to put '/' in front of #, but the result is same, just *123 without #...

I have read the Uri in developer android then found this :
public abstract String getEncodedFragment ()
but I don't really know exactly wht this method does...:)

Anyone can help with this thing...?? :), about how to get that simbol # using Uri.parse..
Thanks in advance.... And I really Apreciate your answer... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From mr. Simon link... I have found the answer :)

```
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:"+Uri.encode("*123#")));
```

So I just added Uri.encode("*123#"); and "#" is still there....

thanks aaaa looot Mr. Simon... hehehe.. :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding.

Answer (score 3):

`encodedHash`encode the the # char. you can go with it

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#");
startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.DIAL",
Uri.parse("tel:"+ "*123"+ encodedHash)));
```

Comment: yeaah.. I'm using Uri.encode.. and it works.. .thank you.. ;)

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible I think, a quick search will guide you to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11774884/android-how-to-make-a-call-that-includes-or-p-in-the-dial)

For more details look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16570488/how-to-use-uri-parse-with-at-the-end)

Comment: Thank you let me take a look at your links... :)

Comment: No issues, I hope they help you.

Comment: If you have multiple correct answers and you accept another one, at least upvote the other correct ones which helped :)

Comment: Done...ehehe... Thanks Mr.Simon... I'm still new bie here too.. :D